# How to make a contour plot in WPF?

Tags: wpf, graph, contour

I am going to make a contour plot of some data. I have a component called Telerik and a component called SciChart for making graphs. I have looked at their homepages and searched the internet and i dont think they support contour plots.

So how would i make a contour plot in WPF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use https://oxyplot.codeplex.com/.

it is better documented than d3 and currently supported.

Comment: Thx a lot, i see that it features contourseries as i wanted!

Answer (score 2):

There is a [question](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/chart/contour-plot.aspx) on Telerik site with the question, that may be interesting for you too.

And also [Dynamic Data Display](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex.

Comment: thx ill take a look at this, Dynamic Data Display looks nice.